# DRF: What validation takes place when calling <model_instance>.save()?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I've read a lot of posts here in SO, and the more I read, the more confused I get.

This came about from creating unitttests, where I often need to create an instance of a model, then change fields, and call `instance.save()`.  But it's not just for unittests.  For my multi-tenant site, there's a create_tenant() method (for example), which eventually calls create().  And when updating a tenant, some "save()" method is called, though it's not clear in my mind yet how, when, or which one is called.

The first time I tried saving an instance in my unittests, the validations didn't run - my test was checking for raising a ValidationError, and I didn't get that assertion error.

I then created a save() method in my model class and called self.full_clean().  That caused the validations to run, but I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/code/src/virticl_api/tenants/tests/test_models.py", line 110, in test_invalid_schema_names
    self.test_tenant.save()
  File "/code/src/virticl_api/tenants/models.py", line 230, in save
    self.full_clean()       # Run validations
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1152, in full_clean
    raise ValidationError(errors)
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: {'schema_name': ['This field cannot be blank.']}
```

However, this didn't trigger the unittest assertion either because that is the wrong ValidationError.  Note that it is:

```
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError
```

My test assertion is checking for:

```
rest_framework.serializers.ValidationError
```

I know I could import the django.core one as something like `DjangoValidationError` and check for both types, but that's actually one of my issues.  If I get that `This field cannot be blank.` validation error in the production site, it will not be returned as a JSON response that my front-end can handle.  So one thing I don't understand is how to turn an exception raised in django.core into an APIException for DRF?

But my main source of confusion is... when calling instance.save() on a model instance, what validations are being run?  I've read about create(), update(), and save() for serializers - and I know about is_valid(), but when I tried to use is_valid() on the model instance, it wasn't defined.

I'm hoping for guidance on where exactly I should put my validations, and how to call save() on an instance so that those validations always get executed.

Comment: No validation is called on instance save. Validation goes on the serializer.

Comment: So how to invoke validations when we need to do instance.save()?  In our system, that will actually occur quite often - as opposed to the front-end hitting the "update" endpoint, which will be a put/patch to the appropriate view, which will invoke the validations on the serializer(s).  Which brings up another point... there are validations (potentially) defined for each field in the model; and there are validations in the serializers (and, it seems, validations in django.core - or perhaps DRF).  Are the field validations defined in the model invoked by the serializer is_valid() method?

Comment: Of course they are. But if you need to run them before instance save, then you should do that explicitly. See the docs on [validating objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects).